Little Girl Singing Farashaka in Movie from Childhood
In the mid 1980s, there was a movie I remember seeing, but only recall bits of (because I was very young). My google attempts have failed me and I'm hoping to see if anyone can help identify it.
I figure it was probably made in the 1980s or late 1970s. There was a little girl, and she had a wooden doll (pretty sure at least). I remember her singing "farashaka" or "Frere Jacques" (spelling). I also think she might of been caught or trapped in a cave or well or something like that.
Any help identifying the movie would be greatly appreciated.

more information is required. What language was spoken? Was it in color?

Thanks Ahmad. The movie was in English, but that particular song was obviously in French. I posted an answer with what I think the movie was from additional googling.

"Frère Jacques" is the name of the nursery rhyme/song.

Had the same memory!

Think I found it after doing more googling. It looks like Disney had a movie in 1977 called 'Child of Glass'. After I found out how to spell 'Frere Jacques' I found others had similar memories. 
After watching the movie, it turned out to be a porcelain doll not a wooden doll. The boy in the movie fell down a well, which describes that memory as well.
